# Will, present continuous, to be going to

Tags: grammar

1. Sally is meeting John at seven o’clock this evening in a restaurant downtown.
2. A: Are you busy this evening?
   B: Yes. I’m going to meet Jack at the library at seven. We’re going to study together.

Why the writer has used "present continuous" for 1 above and "be going to" for the 2 above while the place and time of the event are given.

3. In Section 2 we will prove that.... (in an article)

Is that a correct sentence? Or we should say "In section 2 we are going to prove that...?

Answer (score 1):

For scheduled or timetabled events, we can use **present simple**:

> My flight leaves at 7:35.

We can also use **present continuous** for planned events or activities, and when an activity may go on for some time:

> Sally is meeting John tonight.

The use of **going to** is less formal, and suggests that it's a personal intent rather than a timetabled event:

> I'm going to be a pilot when I grow up

We use **will** :

- when we don't know when something happen: One day I will be able to ...
- to formally express an intent: In section 2, we will prove that ...
- to express opinions: It will probably rain tomorrow
- to express willingness: I will help you with the washing up
- to make offers and promises: I will send you that file tomorrow

You can find out more about ways to talk about the future in this [British Council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/talking-about-the-future) article.

Answer (score 0):

If someone were to tell me "I'm going to meet Jack at the library at seven," I would understand this to mean speaker 'B' is meeting with Jack at 7 o'clock.

One might argue that "I'm going to meet Jack..." emphasizes the act of "going". But, fluent speakers probably would not dwell on this emphasis too much. As a result, other similar constructions that would convey a similar meaning include:

"I'm going to be meeting with Jack at 7"

"I'm meeting with Jack at 7"

"I'm meeting Jack at 7"

Comment: **Going to** might originally have indicated movement, but in modern English it usually does not. If you are sitting in a restaurant, "I am going to order the prawn stir fry" does not indicate that you intend to stand up, find the waitperson and tell them what you want. it's simply an informal version of **will**.